# Where do I instantiate an UpdatePanel in my ASP.NET Codebehind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

#### Background

I have the following code that is supposed to refresh data when a button called `refresh` is clicked.

```
public static void refreshBaan()
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("sp_start_job", conn);
    SqlParameter jobname = new SqlParameter("job_name", "EBS");
    SqlParameter servername = new SqlParameter("server_name", "bnvmsql0a610912");
    comm.Parameters.Add(jobname);
    comm.Parameters.Add(servername);
    comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    conn.Open();
    comm.ExecuteReader();
    conn.Close(); `
}
```

I have an Updatepanel that I want to show when clicked, so naturally I want to put in `Updatpanel1.visible = true;` in the above statement, but it doesn't let me.

#### Question

How can I refresh the data using an updatepanel? Where do I need to instantiate that update panel?

Comment: Use the `{}` button to format the code in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only access instance members of a class in non-static methods.

I would suggest creating a click handler specifically for the button such as:

```
protected void refresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    updatePanel1.Visible = true;
    refreshBaan();
}
```

where the button declaration looks something like:

```
<asp:Button ID="refresh" runat="server" OnClick="refresh_Click" />
```

Comment: Could I simply make my public static void a protected void? Would that effect anyhting you think?

Comment: That might be an option for you. That would mean the `refreshBaan` method could no longer be called from a different class via `ClassName.refreshBaan()`. If the `refreshBaan` method is not called outside of the class it is declared in, then it does not need to be public or static. See the MSDN article on [Static Classes and Static Class Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean, it doesn't work? The code doesn't compile?? Static methods don't have access to non-static page level properties which would include the UpdatePanel. Change the method to be non-static and you should be ok.

Comment: I mean i Get an error in there, states: Doesnt not exsist in the current context.

Comment: That's a compile time error for the reason I explained above. Rather than rewrite his answer, look at the one given my Chris Shouts above.

Answer (score 0):

This might help: http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/updatepanel-control/